# How to execute a java class after cucumber tests in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, testing, cucumber

I am new to tests and Maven and was asked to work with Cucumber.
I manage to have good results but I still have to deal with the import of these results in Testlink.

To do that, I found a simple solution (http://www.qualifiez.fr/journaldutesteur/index.php?article29/une-api-java-pour-s-interfacer-avec-testlink) but the fact is that there is no maven dependency that matches with the proposed library.

So I choosed to create a XML document whose format corresponds to the one waited by Testlink but I now have another problem : how can I run the java class which contains this code after all my cucumber tests are done ? (and after the report results are done too)

Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with Testlink (and surely can't read French :)) and do not fully understand your setup but generally, if you want to execute any code at a specific phase of your project you can do that with the appropriate Maven lifecycle phase.

For example, if there are some steps that need to be done after all your tests (and other code perhaps) have completed, you can use Maven verify phase for that. If required, you can write a Maven plugin yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try that later I think ! At the moment, I cheated a little by using a TestSuite where I first run my cucumber tests and then I run my java class (which is actually not a real test). It works for the moment but I think I will try one of your solutions to have a "cleaner" code :)